# Clang Format Issue with multiline function declaration parameters

Tags: c++, clang-format

Clang Format is consistently doing this:

```
bool importSomethingIn( const boost::property_tree::ptree& inBoostTree,
                        int inSomeIndex,
                        std::shared_ptr<Something>
                            inSomething,
                        int x,
                        int y );
```

When I want it to do this:

```
bool importSomethingIn( const boost::property_tree::ptree& inBoostTree,
                        int inSomeIndex,
                        std::shared_ptr<Something> inSomething,
                        int x,
                        int y );
```

Note that it is adding a newline and indent before the symbol `inSomething`.  It seems to always be the templated types that cause this behaviour.

How can I stop it from doing this?

Here is my current .clang-format:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
Language: Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: true
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
ColumnLimit: 120
CommentPragmas: ''
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DerivePointerBinding: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: true
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
PointerBindsToType: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: true
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 8
UseTab: Never
```

Edit: I am using the clang format Xcode plugin which I obtained [here](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) on github July 2016 (first installed Alcatraz then clang format plugin with Aclatraz).  I'm not entirely sure where the clang-format binary is, thus haven't seen the version number for the one that came with the plugin.

However, based on the suggestions below I installed clang-format using Homebrew which gave me version 3.9.0.  I then set the Xcode plugin to "use system clang-format" and I got the desired result, so I guess it must have been a bug.

Comment: Which version of clang-format are you using? Using your sample code and .clang-format I get the desired output with clang-format 3.8.0 (on Windows).

Comment: the same - getting the desired output on Mac with clang-format version 3.9.0 (tags/google/stable/2016-06-27) installed with Homebrew; ran clang-format from the command-line with the options file as above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your case seems fine to me on ubuntu 16.04 with clang-format 3.8

- Install clang-format-3.8

  ```
    sudo apt-get install clang-format-3.8
  ```
- In `~/.vimrc`

  ```
    map <F3> :pyf /usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/clang-format-3.8.py<cr>                  
    imap <F3> <C-o>:pyf /usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/clang-format-3.8.py<cr>
  ```
- Use @OP's .clang-format and source code

  ```
    mkdir ~/test
    vim ~/test/.clang-format
    vim ~/test/test.cpp
  ```
- Format test.cpp in vim (using F3), then the result:

  ```
    bool importSomethingIn( const boost::property_tree::ptree& inBoostTree,
                            int inSomeIndex,
                            std::shared_ptr<Something> inSomething,
                            int x,
                            int y );
  ```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer as it lead me to go get v 3.9 with Homebrew and tell the Xcode plugin to "use system clang-format" which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is caused by `ColumnLimit`. I think it's a bug...I had this problem ones and I solved it by changing this variable. Try to set:

```
 ColumnLimit: 0
```

### Reason

The length of `bool importSomethingIn( const boost::property_tree::ptree& inBoostTree, int inSomeIndex, std::shared_ptr<Something>" has 117+-3 chars in dependence of computing invisible chars.` is 117+-3 in dependence of computing invisible characters. `ColumnLimit: 120` has been set and it is one of possible reasons, I think, it has been cut.

Comment: This is not the reason. If it were, then Clang Format would also split the very 1st line, which is longer. But it doesn't.

Comment: It has been cut after 115 characters of text. `ColumnLimit: 120` has been set. `inSomething,` has 12 chars. That's the reason it has been cut. Try to learn compute :) .

Comment: I presume we're meant to consider the number of columns in each line, not since the beginning of the entire declaration. On the offending line, I count 50 characters up to and including the `>` where it gets split. But anyway, from the start of the entire declaration is 163 characters, not 115. So, that doesn't explain it either.

Comment: "bool importSomethingIn( const boost::property_tree::ptree& inBoostTree, 
int inSomeIndex,
std::shared_ptr<Something>" has 117+-3 chars in dependence of computing invisible chars. Do you understand me now?

Comment: OK, the math makes sense now. But my problem is that I'm finding it very hard to believe that Clang Format would do something so stupid as to (A) split a line at a comma but (B) not accordingly reset its character count to 0 for the new line... and instead end up splitting a later line based on the number of characters reached in a hypothetical, non-split 1st line... So to me, either something else is the cause, or you're revealing a bug in Clang Format! Which, if so, must've already been fixed, since **jpw** says they get the desired output using 3.8. So OP would have to specify their version

Comment: I think it's a bug...I had this problem ones and I solved it by changing this variable...but it can be caused by something else too...